# SQL Server 2008: DateDiff() of Min()/ Max() not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datediff

Could you help me out with the following query?

**My goal:**

For each day and for each employee select minimum datetime and the maximum datetime and get the time difference in minutes

**My query :**

```
SELECT 
   PersonalId, Name, LastName, 
   Min(TmsPrick) as MinDatetime, 
   Max(TmsPrick) as MaxDatetime, 
   DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(TmsPrick), MAX(TmsPrick)) AS Expr1
FROM 
   prickTable
GROUP BY 
   DATEPART(dy, TmsPrick), PersonalId, name, lastname, TmsPrick
ORDER BY 
   PersonalId, TmsPrick
```

**Note:**
DATEPART(dy, TmsPrick) = Day of year

**My expected output**

```
  PersonalId | Name      | LastName   | MinDatetime       | MaxDatetime        | Expr1
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   000001    | A         | AC         |2014-01-05 07:12:00|2014-01-05 16:00:00 | 528
   000001    | A         | AC         |2014-01-06 07:08:00|2014-01-05 16:00:00 | 532
   000001    | A         | AC         |2014-01-07 07:11:00|2014-01-07 16:00:00 | 529
   000002    | B         | BD         |2014-01-05 07:11:00|2014-01-05 16:00:00 | 529
```

**The output I'm getting:**

```
  PersonalId | Name      | LastName   | MinDatetime       | MaxDatetime        | Expr1
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   000001    | A         | AC         |2014-01-05 07:12:00|2014-01-05 16:00:00 | 1053168
   000001    | A         | AC         |2014-01-06 07:08:00|2014-01-05 16:00:00 | 532
   000001    | A         | AC         |2014-01-07 07:11:00|2014-01-07 16:00:00 | 529
   000002    | B         | BD         |2014-01-05 07:11:00|2014-01-05 16:00:00 | 1053169
```

Any idea why my output shows such differences?

Thanks

**Note:** The values in Tmsprick may vary from several a day to 2 in a week. The table contains values from over 3 years.

Comment: GROUP BY DATEPART(dy,TmsPrick) ??

Comment: Well, for starters, why aren't you using the same columns on which you calculated the `MAX` and `MIN` date?. For those you are using `TmsPrick` and for the difference in minutes you are using `tijdstip`

Comment: @Lamak. Good point. I altered the columnnames from dutch somewhat more english. But i seem to have forgotten some names. Will change em directly

Comment: Your output does not correspond to the query.  The query is aggregating by `tmsprick`, so the `min()` and `max()` values should be the same.

Comment: unfortunately this is the output i'm actually getting. I know there should be a more easy way of becoming the same result. But somehow it is unknown to me.

Comment: You have way too many items in your GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the query that you want is:

```
SELECT PersonalId, Name, LastName,
       Min(TmsPrick) as Mintime, Max(TmsPrick) as Maxtime, 
       DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(TmsPrick), MAX(TmsPrick)) AS Expr1
FROM prickTable
GROUP BY PersonalId, name, lastname, cast(TmsPrick as date)
ORDER BY PersonalId, max(TmsPrick);
```

This will give the the "elapsed" time on each day, because the first and last "tmsprick".

Comment: absolutely brilliant! Thanks mate, i own you one. Output is perfect now! :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, without seeing the source data it's hard to know for sure, but you're using different date columns in the `MAX`/`MIN` and `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT 
    PersonalId, 
    Name, 
    LastName, 
    Min(TmsPrick) as MinDatetime, 
    Max(TmsPrick) as MaxDatetime , 
    DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(tijdstip), MAX(tijdstip)) AS Expr1
                     ^-- should be TmsPrick?
```

Comment: In addition, the query is aggregating by `TmsPrick` and including that in the `min()` and `max()` clauses.

Comment: Changed it in the 'problem description'. +1 though for pointing it out!